# using device width in media query

Tags: css, media-queries

Two column display, left column has important stuff - right column not so important.

What I want on mobile with a device-width smaller than X is -

left column has width set to the device-width
right column has width set to 50% of device-width or 270px, whichever is smaller.

I can't seem to get that to work, what I've tried (left column is main) inside my media query:

```
main {
float: left;
width: device-width;
}
```

However it seems to keep picking up the width for main defined earlier in the CSS before the media query. And yes the media query is active, I set the body to a different background color to make sure.

How do I specify width of a container relative to device width? 100% device width for main, and 50% of device width for the side div.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if to do something like this in the media queries:

```
body {
    width: @device-width + 270px;
}
```

Ideally `main` takes 100% of device-width, and sidebar shows on scroll.